# A practical way of formatting explicit content

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, standards

As a blogger, I want to mark any content in my CMS based on how explicit it is (violent, erotic, spoiler, obscene and so on..). Is there a proper practical library and standard for this?

I have read about RTA, ICRA, PICS and W3C POWDER, but they mark entire page with meta or header. POWDER seems too complex - as far as I understood, it adds metadata outside of the page? Can you provide a simple useful example, if I use with HTML5 doctype.

What I want is a way to mark HTML elements based on their rating. I would also like it to be compliant with any parental filtering. It would also be nice to add EXIF data into images to have them filtered independent of the context.

Comment: Human intervention seems to be the best way to go IMHO. But good luck finding an automation library / implementation :)

Comment: I don't need automation yet. I want to mark it myself, I just need a microformat for this

Comment: Why don't you create a document for it and submit it to microformats.org? Then tag your html elements accordingly and with some javascript you'll be good to go

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's not much use for flagging explicit content outside of censorship of said content.  And to that end, I say "down with internet censorship!" :-)

Comment: You might be able to do it through javascript. Maybe when someone posts something, you check for keywords you identify and append a label or badge or image if any of the words you flagged are present using css and jquery's inner html. If that sounds like what you want I could work on a sample.

Comment: ^ With that you could have a [SPOILER] box that the users could click to reveal content

Comment: I would make a file that contains any flag-able content, then check your posts against it replacing/surrounding with a custom id that will add the scripted display functionality... make your own standard

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware there aren't any widely used standards that can do what you've described. Also, what is the end-goal? For browsers to automatically recognize (and somehow handle/filter) the explicit content?

If you plan on handling the filtering yourself, you can use HTML5 custom data attributes. With them you can do something like:

```
<li class="blogpost" data-rating="G"> [content] </li>
```

And then use that custom attribute to filter/hide the content with JavaScript, CSS, PHP, or whatever other language, for example:

```
li.blogpost[data-rating="R"] { [some styling] }
```

The options on how to handle this paradigm are extremely broad. This isn't exactly a standard, and would obviously require a fair amount of planning and coding. However it would allow you to filter the content based on metrics you define. This type of solution would pair well with a simple login system as suggested in other comments, wherein the users could select what content they want to filter. You could also define age limits for it, or use any number of other options.

This probably won't give you any automatic standards-based filters or anything like that, but such technologies are not widely supported anyways, as far as I know.

If this isn't even close to what you're looking for, could you provide more details on how you want the end product to function?

Comment: Yes, my thoughts for custom solution were the same. Still what does "R" actually **mean**? There are lots of rating systems and just making one up for specific country would be dead-end. So it should be more semantic and multivalued. But at the same time not too over-engineered. Like data-violence="80%" data-nudity="4%". Or maybe instead of % use labels.. so it should be extendable too.

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov - Numeric values sounds like an even better idea. It still wouldn't be totally "automated," but you could do something like present the user with a way to set their thresholds for "violence"/"nudity"/etc before they see any content, and filter it after that point. The "R" and "G" were just examples of the many possibilites :]

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no microformat, i've decided to make one. Named it xrate 1.0, wrote an [article about it](http://kurapov.name/eng/tech/explicit_content_format/) and added [draft to microformats.org](http://microformats.org/wiki/xrate)

Basically its about rating content from 0-100 based on danger with theses HTML attributes:

- `data-xrate-lang` - Obscene language
- `data-xrate-sex` - Romantic, erotic, pornographic
- `data-xrate-nude` - Level of nudity
- `data-xrate-disgust` - Might cause disgust (shit, larvae, decomposition)
- `data-xrate-violence` - Violence and its results - weapons, wounds, dead bodies, blood
- `data-xrate-asocial` - Smoking, alcohol, drugs, gambling, prostitution
- `data-xrate-blink` - Blinking animation that might cause eplilepsy
- `data-xrate-spoiler` - Story is retold
- `data-xrate-camera` - If application (flash/applet?) gains access to videocamera
- `data-xrate-malware` - If resource can cause infection (viruses, trojans etc.) on viewer's machine

Please notify if there is a better solution.

Comment: Very cool, great work! If I ever need this sort of system I'll be sure to try it out

Comment: I don’t think that using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) is appropriate for this use case: "Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data **private to the page** or application" […] "These attributes are **not intended for use by software that is independent of the site** that uses the attributes." (bolded by me)

Comment: in that case, the question is still open

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this while browsing for a solution for you

http://www.ehow.com/how_7580400_filter-explicit-content-apache-server.html

Maybe it will help you

> Instructions
>
> ### 1
>
> Download and install the mod_sed Apache module (see
>   [Resources](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_sed.html)). Some hosting accounts may already have this Apache module
>   installed; in this case, contact your Web hosting provider to check if
>   this module is already available.
>
> ### 2
>
> Log in to your Web server and open your "httpd.conf" file in
>   Notepad. This file is found in the Apache folder if using a local Web
>   server and in the "/etc/httpd/conf" folder on most hosting accounts.
>   If you are unable to locate this file, contact your Web hosting
>   service provider for assistance.
>
> ### 3
>
> Add the commands to
>   filter explicit content. For example, to automatically replace the
>   word "damn" to "darn" in all HTML files, type in the following in your
>   "httpd.conf" file:
>
> AddOutputFilter Sed html
>
> OutputSed "s/damn/darn/g"
>
> ### 4
>
> Save your changes.
>
> Read more: How to Filter Explicit Content in the Apache Web Server |
>   eHow.com
>   http://www.ehow.com/how_7580400_filter-explicit-content-apache-server.html#ixzz1rw85S300

Comment: You misunderstood. I dont want to hide or replace orignal content with web-server. It still should be served, maybe with some progressive enchancement, based on formatting, notifying browser of how dangerous it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a meta tag for rating: `name="rating" content="general"`, however from what I understand it's not really used by many the industry so might be a little pointless - I can't speak regarding filtering software though.

I've never heard of anything in the EXIF for images regarding a rating.

If something is *that* sensitive, it should be behind an age checked login, if not, you should trust in the user and their automatic filtering if they use it.

Comment: I don't want to mark entire page. Yes, I can custom-design and protect  content from spoilers and whatever content I might have. But i want it to be a standard.

Comment: A login system is pretty standard ;) There's no HTML markers that I'm aware of to tag something RE it's maturity rating though.